# Create a .gz file using maven

Tags: maven

Maven assembly doesn't seem to support gz format. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

I can't change to use tar.gz or something else as .gz has been hard coded in some scripts that I don't have permissions to update.

Any idea would be much appreciated?

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure it doesn't support tar.gz?

I think if you do this:

```
<assembly>
  <id>bundle</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>src/main/output</directory>
      <outputDirectory>output</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Then if you do this: `mvn clean assembly:assembly` then Maven should create a tar.gz file.

What is the result you got?

Comment: Hi Alexandre, thanks for your comment. your are correct, tar.gz is supported by assembly plugin but what I want is .gz.